# How to re-enable the links manager?

Tags: links, admin-menu

There is no links manager in the admin_menu of Wordpress 3.5.1 anymore. I'm creating a custom add_links_page, and I'm having a hard time with the making a plugin.

Do I need to initialize something to show the links page?

Comment: Maybe you can re-enable the _Link Manager_ via this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/link-manager/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's commonly activated through:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_link_manager_enabled', '__return_true' );
```

The suggested `Link Manager` plugin only contains this code line.

Answer (score 1):

Or go in you wp database, in the (wp_)options table find the option "link_manager_enabled" and change the value from 0 to 1 (option_id should be 86)

Comment: Thanks so much :-) I know you've posted this so long ago, but it still works! (`option_id` seems to be 84 in WP 6+, but otherwise, it's precisely what you've written). Personally, I prefer a database option to changing the `functions.php` file, because I tend to change themes with some regularity and keep forgetting to make those manual changes; whereas the database will remain stable for far longer periods. Others, however, may feel less comfortable tinkering with the database, or, worse, have no easy access to it... so it's good to have some options!

Answer (score 1):

To re-enable the link manager, add the following line to your theme's `functions.php` file (child theme recommended):

```
 add_filter( 'pre_option_link_manager_enabled', '__return_true' );
```